# Cisco WAN failover without routing

Tags: cisco, wan, failover

I'd like to have my Cisco router failover from a primary WAN to a secondary WAN interface when the primary stops routing traffic. Neither WAN is running any routing protocol, these are residential-type WAN connections (ie, DHCP).

I don't have any need for maintaining source addresses. In either case the traffic would be NAT'd out whatever the appropriate WAN is.

How do I configure this setup in iOS?

If it matters, I have a Cisco 890-series branch router. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: OK, then do what you described. What is your question?

Comment: Question is How do I configure this in iOS. I'll clarify the questions.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking are explicitly off-topic here. You can try to ask this question on [su].

Comment: Maybe but this is how I learn about networking. I use professional equipment and real world scenarios. The underlying media is less relevant. If I were doing on behalf of one of my small business clients, who increasingly need internet redundancy this would also be a valid inquiry.

Comment: @RonMaupin Not many home networks have their own ASNs / IPv6 allocations. This is not a typical scenario the policy refers to.

Comment: Many home networks have their own IPv6 allocations. This is pretty common, especially since almost all the cable and DSL providers claim to be fully IPv6 compliant now. Comcast claims it provides IPv6 to 100% of its residential users. If you object to this question being put on hold, you can take it up on [meta], as it explains in the box above.

Comment: I use Cisco enterprise equipment for my home network on a cable modem. Any questions I may have about this are off-topic here because home/residential networking is explicitly off-topic here. As it says, "_Network Engineering Stack Exchange is for asking questions about professionally managed networks in a business environment._" That doesn't apply to home networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your IOS has IPSLA you should be able to:

- create a ping object for each router (ping something out on the WAN)
- use HSRP on the LAN interfaces
- devices use HSRP address as default gateway
- track the ping object to alter HSRP priority appropriately

Comment: How can I tell if my router has IPSLA?

Comment: conf t then ip sla ? I think

Comment: IP SLA works if you can have the address of an upstream device to track, but it doesn't seem to help with DHCP on a single router. Also, HSRP on the LAN is useless unless you have two routers, which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: Can IP SLA be used to add/withdraw routes? I think IP SLA plus the AD that @RonMaupin described would be a workable combination. 1) Suppress the DHCP default route. 2) ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 eth 0 dhcp 100; ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 eth 1 dhcp 50; 3) then use IP SLA to change the AD 100 route to an AD 25 route based on reachability (anything would work e.g. 8.8.8.8)

Comment: @Pablo, the AD of the DHCP default route is so high that any route you configure with a lower AD will take precedence, and the DHCP default route _will_ be suppressed. IP SLA is useful to track your upstream router, but you will need to know its address when you configure IP SLA, and you can't know that with DHCP. Since this is for a business, you should really get a static route, at least on the primary WAN circuit.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thanks, that's a good point about introducing the route. I don't need to manage the metric, i just need to introduce/withdraw the failover route. In terms of knowing the upstream IP, that's generally true but not what I'm looking for. Testing 8.8.8.8 (Google public DNS which is what I use) is a good proxy for "can i reach the internet". Also this is a home setup, not a business setup, so I can't justify the cost of a business plan.

Comment: @Pablo, you cannot simply test for something like `8.8.8.8` since that is reachable from either WAN circuit. You need to test for something that is only reachable from the WAN circuit in question. If the primary WAN circuit goes down, you will stop being able to reach `8.8.8.8`, but when the backup come up, you will again be able to reach `8.8.8.8`, so you will switch back to the down circuit, and the cycle will repeat.

Comment: @RonMaupin I think that depends on how the ping command is configured. My understanding is the ping command can be bound to a specific interface so the traffic would use the default route for that interface. Perhaps I'm mistaken, but something like this: ping ip 8.8.8.8 source gigabitEthernet 8 (assuming that's possible with IP SLA)

Comment: Looks like ip-sla icmp-echo can be bound to a specific interface: icmp-echo 8.8.8.8  source-interface GigabitEthernet 8 - does that sound right @marctxk

Comment: @RonMaupin, you're right I missed the fact that it's a single router.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to use AD to create floating static routes. I assume you are using a default static route. Use one for each WAN connection, and specifically set the AD on each. The lower AD is preferred. When the preferred port is down, the route will be withdrawn from the routing table, and the route with the next lowest AD will be preferred.

Something like this:

```
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 <Interface 1> <PE address 1> 5
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 <Interface 2> <PE address 2> 10
```

Comment: Can you clarify what AD is? And what if the link isn't down but just unreachable (consider a failed router upstream)

Comment: AD is administrative distance. It tells the router how trustworthy the route is compared to other routes which are the same. If you get the same route using RIP, EIGRP, OSPF, iBGP, and eBGP, the route from eBGP will be preferred because the AD is 20, but if it goes down, then the route from EIGRP will be preferred since the AD is 90. If your upstream router fails, then the link should fail. You can include the upstream router's address, too.

Comment: How would I assign AD on DHCP generated default routes?

Comment: Don't accept default routes from the interface.

Comment: Looking at a Cisco router that gets a default route from the carrier because of DHCP, the default route has an AD of 254, which is the highest it can be without being unreachable. Any you assign with a lower AD will take precedence.

Comment: How do I configure DHCP not to create the default route? I'm not convinced this handles the case where there's an upstream (by which I mean not the immediate neighbor) failure. The physical link is from the router to the cable modem but there could be outages such that interface is still up/up but traffic isn't routable over the interface

Comment: Any upstream router which is not your immediate neighbor is out of your control. ISP usually have pretty good redundancy. How far into the Internet are you wanting to be able to check. You really have no idea how your traffic is routed on the Internet. I can tell you that a connection to a cable modem will go down/down if the network beyond it has a problem. You can simply check what is, or is not, in your immediate reach. If you really want to get complex, I suggest you hire someone to help you. AD is a very basic concept.

Comment: You should also probably get static IP addresses for your business, at least on the primary WAN circuit.

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand AD. It looks like as of 12.3(9) you can do something like this: ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 <interface> dhcp <metric> ; this would let me control the metric for both uplinks. I just need a way to detect routability and switch.

Comment: When the interface goes down, the route is withdrawn from the routing table. That happens automatically. Unless your business is willing to spend a little more for a static route, there is not a whole lot more you can do.

Comment: Thank you but the disconnect is that when Comcast has an outage it's sometimes not directly observable in the last mile. Sometimes there's a failure at the head end that results in link layer working, but not being able to route to the internet. Also both of my uplinks would be DHCP (I'm planning on having a wifi-ethernet bridge join my neighbor's wifi, who's on FIOS).

Comment: This is for a home network?

Comment: That's correct.